# How to set session-timeout in basic authentication (http header) using restful webservices

Tags: http-headers, basic-authentication, session-timeout

```
<security-constraint>
<display-name>allUsers</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>LoginConfig</web-esource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint><role-name>*</role-name></auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
<role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

In my application, I used Basic authentication mechanism. I required set     session-timeout for this. For this, I used session timeout tag.but, It is not working for this. I check existing stack overflow topics I found I need to set session-timeout through HTTP header. How I need to set in session-timeout in HTTP header in my application?
can anybody please response? Thanks in Advance.
How I need to set the Session timeout in Basic authentication application?

Comment: I removed the signature in your post; it's not necessary as you'll see your name at the bottom of the post anyway.

Comment: Can you please let me know above requirement is understandable?Still I am waiting for your response.Kindly please provide is some solution on above issue.